# Sufficient conditions for a mobius transformation to map the unit circle to itself.

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

> Find necessary and sufficient conditions for a Mobius transformation $T(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ to map the unit circle to itself. So if $\gamma$ is a circle, $T(\gamma)=\gamma$.
>
> I've worked out the necessary conditions. Namely, if $T(\gamma)=\gamma$, then
>
> 1. $|a|^2+|b|^2=|c|^2+|d|^2$
> 2. $a\bar{b}=\bar{d}c$
> 3. $\bar{a}b=d\bar{c}$
>
> Source: Conway's Complex Functions of One Variable

How does one go about showing sufficiency? Should I simply assume conditions 1),2) and 3) and try to prove that $T(\gamma)=\gamma$? If so I can simply claim that all the implications I used to get these conditions also work backwards. Or just show that $|\frac{az+b}{cz+d}|=1$ by these conditions, which is rather simple. Is that all there is to this? I just wish the whole "necessary and sufficient" language was scrapped for some direct notation.

As an aside, I'm wondering if I'm using the words "necessary" and "sufficient" correctly in this context. Is what I showed in the first part the necessary conditions (that's what makes sense to me semantically, because they are necessary once I've assumed the map), or are they the sufficient conditions?

Comment: Conditions 2 and 3 are the same essentially.

Comment: @MattSamuel Right, they are one conjugation apart, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209308/can-we-characterize-the-m%C3%B6bius-transformations-that-maps-the-unit-circle-into-it

Comment: Thx for ur link, that thread is botched because the op asked about the unit disk initially, so people gave him answers to that question, and then he changed it to a circle, some people even answer with the typical mobius transformation that maps the unit disk to itself in an attempt to answer his circle question... that hardly gives necessary and sufficient conditions to my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The map $T(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ sends the unit circle to itself  if and only if for any $\zeta$ in the circle, $|T(\zeta)|=1$. Now you just have to translate this into conditions on the coefficients.

$|T(\zeta)|=1$ is equivalent to 
$$
|a|^2 + |b|^2 + 2Re(a\bar{b} \zeta) = |c|^2 +|d|^2+ 2Re(c\bar{d}\zeta)
$$

Since $T$ is determined by the image of three points, just evaluate the equation above for three distinct values of $\zeta$ and you'll get the necessary and sufficient conditions. For $\zeta = 1, i, -1$, you'll get the conditions 1) and 2).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As my question suggested, I've followed this process precisely. My real question is, why does this process give me the necessary AND sufficient conditions? Isn't this an if and only if statement? We started off supposing $|T(z)|=1$, and we found the restraints on $a,b,c$ and $d$ to get the necessary conditions. Now, shouldn't we work backwards to show that these conditions are also sufficient? Or perhaps they are not and we require a few more conditions for sufficiency. And of course I might be using the words necessary and sufficient backwards, but that's fixable.

Comment: Untill we achieve the equation, every thing is "if and only if". And the equation is true for every $\zeta$ if and only if it is valid for three distinct values, thats the point.

Comment: If we change the points we'll get equivalent conditions

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, mobius transformations are uniquely determined by their actions on three points.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't believe that it is that fact alone which is used for the converse. We also have to recall that the image of a circle under a Mobius transformation is a circle. So the image of the unit circle is going to be a circle. The condition being satisfied for $1,i,-1$ means that $|T(1)|=|T(i)|=|T(-1)|=1$ i.e., the images of $1,i,-1$ lie in the unit circle. Hence the image must be the unit circle.

Comment: @HritRoy "We also have to recall that the image of a circle under a Mobius transformation is a circle." This would be  nice shortcut. However it follows directly from that equation as it imposes the right conditions on $a,b,c,d$.

Answer (score 0):

here we have a unit circle $\gamma$. we want to find the sufficient and necessary condition such that $T(\gamma)=\gamma$.

we know that for every point $z$ in the unit circle, $\bar{z}$ is also in it. so $|\bar{z}|=1$ so we have $|z^2|=1$ and $z\bar{z}=1$.

$|T(\gamma)|$ must be also equal to $1$. so for every $z$, $T(z)\bar{T(z)}=1$. after solving and simplify,  we have:

$z\bar{z}(a\bar{a}-c\bar{c})+z(a\bar{b}-c\bar{d})+\bar{z}(\bar{a}b-\bar{c}d)+(b\bar{b}-\bar{d}d)=0$

it must be just like $z\bar{z}-1=0$.

so :

$a\bar{a}-c\bar{c}=1$

$a\bar{b}-c\bar{d}=0$

$\bar{a}b-\bar{c}d=0$

$b\bar{b}-\bar{d}d=-1$

this yields the sufficient condition  $|a|^2+|b|^2=|c|^2+|d|^2 $ $(*)$

to finding the necessary condition we assume that $c=\lambda\bar{b}$ and this yields 
$d=\frac{\bar{a}}{\lambda}$.
from inserting $d$ and $c$ in $(*)$, $|\lambda|$ must be equal to $1$. and if we take $\lambda=e^{i\alpha}$, $T(z)=e^{i\alpha}\frac{az+b}{\bar{b}z+\bar{c}}$ is the necessary condition.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the mapping of the complex plane G(w) =2w^2 on itself. What happens to the unit circle (consisting of complex numbers such that |z|=1)? How many preimages does one point have with this mapping?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Comments & hints should be given as comments rather than answers, if they fit.