# Characterization of linear fractional transformations that maps the unit disc into itself

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

I am reading the paper ["ADJOINTS OF COMPOSITION OPERATORS ON HILBERT
SPACES OF ANALYTIC FUNCTIONS"](http://www.uam.es/personal_pdi/ciencias/dragan/respub/2005-07adjoint.pdf) by MARIA J. MARTIN AND DRAGAN VUKOTIC.
In Section 1.1 they say the linear fractional transformation $\phi(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ maps the unit disc into itself   if and only if
$$|b\overline{d}-a\overline{c}|+|ad-bc|\leq |d|^2-|c|^2 .$$

I can't neither prove it nor see the reference. Could anyone please suggest something.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209308/can-we-characterize-the-m%C3%B6bius-transformations-that-maps-the-unit-circle-into-it) deals with a similar topic.  Their function is explicitly in the form of a Blashke Factor though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have $|d|^2-|c|^2>0$ or else there is a pole inside the disk.

To get the formula (I remember doing this long time ago, it slowly comes back) there is a little trick, to precompose by a suitable conformal map preserving the disk but making our transformation linear. So define
$$ M(z) = \frac{z-\alpha}{1-\bar{\alpha} z} $$
using the value: $\alpha = \bar{c}/\bar{d}$ (modulus <1). Then $M\in {\rm Aut} ({\Bbb D})$ and we get (you should carry out this calculation on a piece of paper):

$$ f\circ M(z) = \frac{ b\bar{d}-a \bar{c}}{d\bar{d}-c\bar{c}} + 
   z \frac{d a-cb}{d\bar{d}-c\bar{c}}=q+rz$$
The image of ${\Bbb D}$ is now clearly a disk with center $q$ and radius r. The condition then reads $|q|+r\leq 1$ which translates into the inequality that you stated above.

Answer (score 0):

the easy thing to remember is that $\phi(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$  maps the upper half plane to itself when $a,b,c,d$ are real and $ad-bc > 0.$

Mapping back and forth between upper half plane and disc is easy enough, let me work that out.

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
i & 1 \\
1 & i
\end{array}
\right)
$$
takes the (open) upper half plane to the disc. Then
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1 & i \\
i & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
takes disc to half plane.