# $\varphi_a(x)=a+(1-|a|^2)\frac{x+a}{|x+a|^2}$ is a diffeomorphism from unit ball to unit ball in $\mathbb R^n(|a|>1)$.

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

I want to prove that $\varphi_a(x)=a+(1-|a|^2)\frac{x+a}{|x+a|^2}$ is a diffeomorphism from unit ball to unit ball in $\mathbb R^2$($a\in \mathbb R^n,|a|>1$, where $||$ is the usual Euclidean norm).

I don't know how to show that $|\varphi_a(x)|<1$ for $|x|<1$ and that $\varphi_a$ is surjective onto the unit ball(is it surjective?). I have tried using a lot of inequalities but they are all fruitless.\

Note that in $\mathbb C$ this is [a linear fractional transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/209407/185631) that sends the unit disk to itself.

Comment: Separate expression with terms of $x$ and $a$ and take the norm $\phi$.

Comment: Do you mean $\varphi_a(x)=a+(1-|a|^2)(\frac{x}{|x+a|^2}+\frac{a}{|x+a|^2})$? I don't see how to continue...

Comment: BTW, for the linear fractional transformation case in $\Bbb C$, you need $|a|<1$ and the map is quite different.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: I would recommend that you start by doing this for $n=1$. You should be able to show that $|\phi_a(x)|\le 1$ if and only if $(1-x^2)(a^2-1)\ge 0$. Next do the same argument for $n>1$ by using dot products.