# Let $\gamma$ be the unit circle. Find a Möbius transformation that transforms $\gamma$ onto $\gamma$ and transforms 0 to $\frac{1}{2}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $\gamma$ be the unit circle. Find a Möbius transformation that transforms $\gamma$ onto $\gamma$ and transforms 0 to $\frac{1}{2}$.

I think it's quite easy to find a Möbius transformation that transforms $\gamma$ onto $\gamma$, since Möbius transformation always maps circle to circle or line. We can actually choose three points on $\gamma$ than solve the Möbius transformation by pluging in numbers. But when we also need $0 \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}$, I have a problems find such map.

And to check the “onto” fashion, can we simply say that the inverse is also a Möbius transformation?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation#Subgroups_of_the_Möbius_group

Comment: `We can actually choose three points on γ than solve the Möbius transformation by pluging in numbers` No, because you don't know what those points transform to, only that their transforms will lie on the unit circle. See the previous comment, and also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209308/can-we-characterize-the-m%C3%B6bius-transformations-that-maps-the-unit-circle-into-it) for a start.

Comment: @dxiv Thanks, got it already~