# Entire function that is a bijection on the unit disk is a rotation

Tags: complex-analysis, rotations, entire-functions

I'm working on this problem

"Let $f$ be an entire function. Suppose $f$ restricted to the unit disk is a bijection. Prove that $f$ is a rotation."

My attempt: It is tempting to use Schwarz lemma. Let $T$ be the linear transformation that maps the unit disk to itself and $T(f(0))=0$ (If I remember it right, $T=\frac{z-f(0)}{1-\overline{f(0)}z}$). Then $|Tf(z)|\leq 1$ in the unit disk and $T(f(0))=0$.

So, if I can show that $|Tf(z)|=|z|$ for some nonzero $z$, we are done by the lemma. I want to say $Tf$ achieves maximum on the unit circle. So if the maximum is 1, $|T(f(z))|=1=|z|$ for some $z$ there. However I am stuck here.

Comment: $f(z)= 2z$ is entire but is a bijection of $\Delta(0,1)$ onto its image without being a rotation. Is there any further asumption?

Comment: an idea is to use $T \circ T^{-1}=id$ to get that $|T'(0)(T^{-1})'(0)|=1$ and conclude from there and Schwarz

Comment: @Dl - bijection of the unit disc onto itself if I understand it right - otherwise  one needs to classify the univalent functions on the disc that extend to entire functions and those are many

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All holomorphic bijections of the unit disk onto itself are Möbius transformations  of the form
$$
 T(z) = e^{i\lambda} \frac{z-a}{1-\overline a z}
$$
for some $a \in \Bbb D$ and $\lambda \in \Bbb R$. (See for example [Can we characterize the Möbius transformations that maps the unit disk into itself?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209308/can-we-characterize-the-m%C3%B6bius-transformations-that-maps-the-unit-disk-into-itse).)

If $T$ is the restriction of an entire function $f$ then necessarily $a=0$ (otherwise $f$ would have a pole at $z= 1/\overline a$).

Comment: Thank you. I will look into that site

Comment: it's amazing how you don't use any theorem. Just computations

Comment: in the site you cited,  they proe that Mobius trnasformation which is a bijection on unit disk must have your form. However, in my problem this function is not a Mobius transformation, right?

Comment: @TC: *All* holomorphic bijections of the unit disk are Möbius transformations. I'll see if I can find a reference.

Comment: @TC: See for example Theorem 2.5 here http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~dcheragh/Teaching/2016-F-GCA/2016-F-GCA-Ch2.pdf. The idea is that you apply the Schwarz Lemma to both $f$ and its inverse, and conclude that equality holds.

Comment: thakn you. i will