# Can we characterize the Möbius transformations that map the unit circle into the unit disk?

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

The Möbius transformations are the maps of the form $$ f(z)= \frac{az+b}{cz+d}.$$
Can we characterize the Möbius transformations that map the unit circle
$\{z\in \mathbb C: |z| = 1\}$
into the (closed) unit disk
$\{z\in \mathbb C: |z| \leq  1\}$?

See the related post, but not similar post: [Can we characterize the Möbius transformations that maps the unit disk into itself?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209308/can-we-characterize-the-m%c3%b6bius-transformations-that-maps-the-unit-disk-into-itse)

Comment: It seems to me that your question is answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/209434/42969.

Comment: Well here you only know what happens on the unit \emph{circle}.

Comment: If $|z|=1$ is mapped into the unit circle then the same is true for $|z| \le 1$, according to the maximum modulus principle.

Comment: Well Martin R the Möbius transformation is not holomophic in the unit disc - so I guess this argument is not applicable?

Answer (score 0):

Notice$$\left|\frac{ae^{it}+b}{ce^{it}+d}\right|^2=\frac{(ae^{it}+b)(a^\ast e^{-it}+b^\ast)}{ce^{it}+d)(c^\ast e^{-it}+d^\ast)}=\frac{aa^\ast+bb^\ast+2\Re(ab^\ast e^{it})}{cc^\ast+dd^\ast+2\Re(cd^\ast e^{it})}$$for $t\in\Bbb R$. We wish to identify those $a,\,b,\,c,\,d\in\Bbb C$ for which the above has modulus $\le1$, i.e. $\min_{t\in\Bbb R}(A+B\cos t+C\sin t)\ge0$ with$$A=cc^\ast+dd^\ast-aa^\ast-bb^\ast,\,B=2\Re(cd^\ast-ab^\ast),\,C=2\Im(ab^\ast-cd^\ast).$$The desired constraint is $A\ge\sqrt{B^2+C^2}=|ab^\ast-cd^\ast|$.