# How do I find all linear fractional transformations which map the circle $\{z\in \Bbb{C}:|z-2|=3\}$ to itself?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, linear-fractional-transformation

I have the following problem.

> I need to find all linear fractional transformations $f$ such that $f(\{|z-2|=3\})=\{|z-2|=3\}$

I thought that maybe one could use that a LFT maps symmetric points with respect to $\{|z-2|=3\}$ to symmetric points with respect to $\{|z-2|=3\}$. But I'm a bit confused since I need to find all of them not only one.
Could someone give me a hint?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I know little about the topic but one method that seems possible is considering the maps circle -> $\mathbb{H}$ -> $\mathbb{H}$ -> circle, described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/209393/948125)

Comment: the one I find easy to remember:   the upper half plane is mapped to itself by $\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$  where $a,b,c,d$  are real and $ad-bc > 0.$   There are simple maps between the half plane and the standard unit disc $|z|  < 1.$  Finally simple maps between your disc and the standard.