# Understanding Blaschke factors

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

It is known that the automorphisms of the unit disk in the complex plane $\mathbb{D}$ = $\{z \in \mathbb{C}:|z| < 1\}$ all take the form:
$$\psi_\alpha(z)= e^{i\theta}\frac{z-\alpha}{1-\overline\alpha z}$$
where $\theta \in S^1$, and $\alpha \in \mathbb{D}$. The former factor $e^{i\theta}$ evidently depicts a rotation, which aligns with some geometric intuition regarding one family of conformal maps from the disk to itself.

However, I was wondering whether there was some intuitive way to make sense of the right-hand mapping - I've shown its properties of conformality and idempotence, but I still feel like it comes "out of nowhere", and I was interested to know if there is a way to understand these Blaschke factors and how they act on the disk beyond the purely symbolic proofs that they are automorphisms. Thank you so much.

Comment: Great question. The answer has two parts. (1) Blaschke factors are a special type of Möbius transform (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation) for which many beautiful visualizations and explanations exist. (2) In fact, Blaschke factors are exactly those Möbius transforms that send the disk to itself (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209308/can-we-characterize-the-m%C3%B6bius-transformations-that-maps-the-unit-disk-into-itse).