# Local Isometries from the disk to itself are Mobius maps?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, isometry

Let $f:\mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ be a local isometry. I want to show that is an automorphism (i.e. a Mobius map).

Here's one brief argument I've come across:

"By the Pick Theorem (in Milnor - Dynamics in One Complex Variable page 23), we have that $f:\mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ is a covering map, therefore it must be an automorphism of $\mathbb{D}$."

I was wondering if anyone could clarify this statement a little bit, or provide an alternative argument? Why must local isometric covering maps of the disk to itself to automorphisms?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By a local isometry, do you mean a local isometry with respect to the hyperbolic metric on $\mathbb{D}$?

Comment: Yes, that's right I do :)

Comment: Because $\mathbb D$ is simply-connected, any connected covering must be an isomorphism.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by a connected covering?

Comment: First, verify that Mobius transformations are isometry. Suppose $f$ is an isometry and $f(0) = a$. Find a Mobius transformation $M$ such that $M(a) = 0$. $M\circ f$  is an isometry that maps $0$ to $0$. Show that this has to be a rotation and therefore a Mobius transformation. Conclude that $f$ is a Mobius transformation.

Comment: Do we use the Schwarz lemma to show this is a rotation? If so, I'm not sure how to show that $\vert (M \circ f)'(0) \vert$ = 1 @Deane

Comment: I’m not using any complex analysis at all. I never use the fact that $f$ is holomorphic. But I am assuming $f$ preserves orientation.

Comment: Ah ok, I think I see. For any $z \in \mathbb{D}$, we have the distance from $z$ to 0 is the same as the distance from $f(z)$ to 0, and this is only possible if each point is rotated, is that right?

Comment: @Deane Sorry for the bother, but I think I've confused myself. How are Mobius maps isometries? For example, the map $z \rightarrow z/2 $ is a Mobius map, but here distance is not preserved.

Comment: Sorry. Not all mobius transformations are isometries of the disk. My comment is correct if you restrict to the right subset. See  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209308/can-we-characterize-the-m%c3%b6bius-transformations-that-maps-the-unit-disk-into-itse

Comment: @Deane Just to check, are you saying that Mobius maps of the form $\frac{e^{i\theta}(z-a)}{1-\bar{a} z}$ are isometries? If so, I'm a little unsure to see how. Thanks

Comment: Could you say what you know about the hyperbolic plane and when a map is an isometry?

Comment: @Deane I know that the hyperbolic plane is usually given the poincare metric which measures the distance between two points. A map is an isometry if it is bijective and if it preserves the distance between any two points i.e. d(f(z_1)-f(z_2))=d(z_1 - z_2). Admittedly, the field is still a little new to me, so I thank you for bearing with me.

Comment: OK. You could try looking at this: http://library.msri.org/books/Book31/files/cannon.pdf