Conformal map between $D-[\alpha,1)$ and $D-[0,1)$
Let $\alpha$ be real, $0 \leq \alpha < 1$. Let $U_{\alpha}$ be the open set obtained from the unit disc by deleting the segment $[\alpha, 1)$

Find an isomorphism of $U_{\alpha}$ with the unit disc from which the segment $[0, 1]$ has been deleted.

I am wondering if the following approach is right:
Proof ?: Note that $f(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ maps circles to circles in $\mathbb{C}^*$ hence take $f(z) = \frac{\alpha-z}{\alpha -1}$ this mobious transform maps $\alpha \to 0$ and $1 \to 1$ and the image of $f$ should be a proper circle because this is just rotating and scaling and shifting. Moreover it is clear that $[\alpha,1]$ maps to $[0,1]$ because conformal implies angle preserving.
Am I missing anything ?

$f$ maps circles to circles, but not necessarily the unit circle to the unit circle.

@MartinR Right I see, but I guess since f is defined on the unit disc (with a slit) by the maximum modulus principle $|f(z)|<1$ (as $f(1) = 1$ ) so it still maps to the unit circle no?

$f(z) = \frac{\alpha-z}{\alpha -1}$ is a linear function, that cannot be the correct solution. – Note that the conformal automorphism of the unit disk are well-known, see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/209308/42969.

Take an automorphism of the unit disk which maps $[\alpha, 1]$ to $[0,1].$
By @Martin R's link it has to be a Möbius transformation of a certain type.
Check that $f(z)=\frac {z-\alpha}{1-\alpha z}$ takes $\alpha, 1,\infty $ to $0,1,-\frac1\alpha,$ respectively.
