# Is there anything special with complex fraction $\left|\frac{z-a}{1-\bar{a}{z}}\right|$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Is there anything special with the form:

$$\left|\frac{z-a}{1-\bar{a}{z}}\right|$$
? With $a$ and $z$ are complex numbers.

In fact, I saw it in a problem:

1. If $|z| = 1$, prove that $|\frac{z-a}{1-\bar{a}{z}}| = 1$
2. If $|z| < 1$ and $|a| < 1$, prove that $|\frac{z-a}{1-\bar{a}{z}}| < 1$

I can easily prove the first one with expansion:

$$z=\cos\theta + i\sin \theta \\ a = m +in$$

But it will be terrible to use in the second one. What's more, I found this form a little special so maybe there is some clever trick **without using expansion**?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: [This is very related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34071/m%C3%B6bius-transforms-that-preserve-the-unit-disk) (I won't go as far as saying it's a duplicate).

Comment: You can factor out $|z|$, which together with $\bar{z} = z^{-1}$ and one more observation gives the identity. Similar considerations also give an argument for (2). The ratio in your display equation is a Mobius transformation (in fact, all are given by products of that ratio and constants of modulus 1). Mobius transformations are precisely the linear fractional transformations that preserve the unit disc. Moreover, they're all invertible and so they form a group under composition that we can identify with $PGL(2, \mathbb{R})$.

Comment: @Travis: The transformation $z\mapsto -\frac{1}{z}$ is also a Moebius transform that does not preserve the unit disc. It is only the ones that you describe that do.

Comment: @Michalis: Thanks for pointing this out, you're right, of course, I just managed to garble the statement during editing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we characterize the Möbius transformations that maps the unit disk into itself?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209308/can-we-characterize-the-m%c3%b6bius-transformations-that-maps-the-unit-disk-into-itse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use $z\overline{z}=|z|^2$ and compare $|z-a|^2$ to $|1-\overline{a}z|^2$.

Have a look at the comments to see why these transformations are special.

Answer (score 1):

We first prove that if $|z|=1$ then $|f(z)|=1$. For we have
$$
|f(z)|=|\frac{z-a}{1-\bar az}|=|\frac 1{\bar z}\frac{z-a}{1-\bar az}|=|\frac {z-a}{\bar z-\bar a}|=1
$$
Now apply maximum principle to get $|f(z)|<1$ for $|z|<1$.