# Show that Möbius transformations that preserve the unit disk are of the matrix form $\tiny \begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ \bar{b} & \bar{a} \end{bmatrix}$

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

Show that Möbius transformations that preserve the unit disk are of the matrix form $$\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ \bar{b} & \bar{a} \end{bmatrix},$$ where $|a|^2 - |b|^2 = 1$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$.

I tried approaching this by noting that these transformations must first and foremost preserve the unit circle. So I looked at whether I'd get anything useful out of seeing what a random matrix $\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$ would need to satisfy in order for, say, $1, -1$ and $i$ to stay on the unit circle. However, I got nothing useful out of that.

I looked at some threads here already (for example, [Möbius Transforms that preserve the unit disk](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34071/m%C3%B6bius-transforms-that-preserve-the-unit-disk)), but none of them seem to help in getting me this form.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A Möbius transformation is a linear-fractional transformation, $f(z) = (az + b)/(cz + d)$.  Perhaps your matrix entries are related to the constants appearing this rational expression, but it cannot be said that the matrix "is" the Möbius transformation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we characterize the Möbius transformations that maps the unit disk into itself?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209308/can-we-characterize-the-m%c3%b6bius-transformations-that-maps-the-unit-disk-into-itse)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that your statement of the result is not quite accurate.  For example, the Mobius transformation
$$f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}=\frac{iz+0}{0z+i}=z$$
clearly preserves the unit disc even though the corresponding matrix
$$\pmatrix{i&0\cr0&i\cr}$$
does not have the form you state.  However, multiplying $a,b,c,d$ by a common factor does not alter $f$, and so we may assume that $ad-bc=1$.  If we suppose that this is the case, then the result is true.

Now note that if $\beta$ is real then the inequation
$$\def\o#1{\overline#1}
  z\o z-\alpha z-\o\alpha\o z+\beta<0$$
can be written as
$$|z-\o\alpha|^2<|\alpha|^2-\beta\ ;$$
this is the open disc with centre $\o\alpha$ and radius $\sqrt{|\alpha|^2-\beta}$ if $\beta<|\alpha|^2$, the empty set otherwise.

A bit of algebra shows that the inverse image of $|f(z)|<1$ is
$$z\o z-\alpha z-\o\alpha\o z+\beta<0$$
with
$$\alpha=\frac{c\o d-a\o b}{a\o a-c\o c}\ ,\quad
  \beta=\frac{b\o b-d\o d}{a\o a-c\o c}\ .$$
Setting $|\alpha|^2-\beta=1$ and simplifying shows that this is the unit disc if and only if
$$c\o d-a\o b=0\ ,\quad b\o b-d\o d=-1\ .$$
We can therefore write
$$a=a(d\o d-b\o b)=\o d(ad-bc)+b(c\o d-a\o b)=\o d\ ,$$
and similarly $b=\o c$.

Comment: Thanks! But how did you get to that inverse image, I don't quite understand how to approach it.

Comment: $|(az+b)/(cz+d)|<1$, multiply out, convert modulus to conjugates, do the algebra.

Comment: I'm trying to do the algebra now, but what do you mean by multiply out and convert modulus to conjugates? Do you mean starting with $|f(z) \bar{f(z)}| < 1$? That's what I'm trying, but I don't see how you get the form that you do.

Comment: Yes, you can start there, though modulus signs are superfluous as $f(z)\overline{f(z)}$ is always a non-negative real.  Then just continue with basic algebra that you learned in elementary school.

Comment: I guess you're right, it does hold. I don't quite see how you excluded the possibility that $|a| = |c|$, though.

Comment: I think you will find that if $|a|=|c|$ then the inverse image of the unit disc is of the form $\gamma z+\o\gamma\o z+\delta<0$, which is not a disc but a half plane.

Comment: Ah, yes, basically the set $\{z \in \mathbb{C}: Re(z) < -\frac{\delta}{2}\}$, right? I guess the last thing that still eluded me was how you obtained $b \bar{b} - d \bar{d} = -1$. I can see $\beta = -1$, but not why the numerator would necessarily be equal to $1$.

Comment: Actually, $Re(\gamma z)<-\delta/2$.  If you substitute the expressions for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ into $|\alpha|^2-\beta=1$ and simplify, I think you should find that $b\o b-d\o d=-1$ drops out.