# How to recognize if a Möbius transformation includes an 'inversion' operation?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation

For my current project, I am looking into [Möbius transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation) from the unit disk onto itself. Such Möbius transformations can be found, for example, by specifying three points and their images on the unit circle. Assume that I have the four parameters $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ of a given Möbius transformation:

$$M(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$$

Sometimes, the Möbius transformation causes an inversion, i.e. a mapping from the inside of the unit disk to the outside of the unit disk and vice versa.

**Now my question**: Is there a way to recognize whether a Möbius transformation induces an inversion directly through the parameters $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$?

Comment: Have you tried writing $z$ in polar coordinates?

Comment: Not yet, no. I'm quite new to the field of complex algebra. How would this help?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4482480/96384, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/34071/96384, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1132830/96384, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1705159/96384, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/209308/96384.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Möbius transformation maps $\frac12+\frac12i$ outside the unit disc, then it indicates that the transformation is an inversion. Now
$$|M(\tfrac12+\tfrac12i)|^2 = \frac{(a+b)^2 + b^2}{(c+d)^2+d^2},$$
and when this is $>1$, you have that $\frac12+\frac12i$ is mapped outside the disc. Thus you could take your condition to be that
$$(a+b)^2+b^2>(c+d)^2+d^2.$$

---

**Edit:** As suggested in runaway44's comment, we can obtain an easier condition by seeing where $0$ is mapped. Indeed,
$$|M(0)| = b/d,$$
so we just need $|b| > |d|$.

Comment: Why not apply $M$ to $0$?

Comment: @runway44 I'm a bit hazy on the details of the Mobius transform, I forget how zero is treated. That would certainly simplify the condition.

Comment: $M(0)=b/d$ and then the condition is $|b|>|d|$.

Comment: Oh yeah, that is actually a very simple solution, runway44. Do you want to post it? Then I can accept it as a solution.

Comment: Well these criteria are sufficient but certainly not necessary. By basic theory, there are tons of Möbius transformations which map $0$ to some $b/d$ in the unit disk, even to $0$, but (say) $0.5$ to $17$, or $-3i$, or $\infty$; or, $\dfrac{z}{z-1}$ maps $0.9$ to $-9$ whilst keeping $0$ fixed, etc.

Comment: Of course, if you already know that the transformation maps the unit *circle* to itself, then it maps the unit disk to itself iff $|b|<|d|$, while it exchanges the inside and the outside of the unit circle iff $|b|>|d|$.